# Why is a SQLite Select statement so much slower than numpy.select? Any way to speed it up?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, sqlite, sqlalchemy

#### What I am trying to do

I am trying to export and import tables between `pandas` and a `sqlite` database. The reasons for doing this are a combination of:

- needing to store certain data in sqlite format, and
- finding the sqlite syntax clearer and easier to read than vectorised numpy operations, when doing things like creating new variables based on nesting multiple if / case when statements

#### My questions

Running a select statement with an in-memory sqlite database is quite slow - it is about 3-5 times slower than using `numpy.select`. My questions are:

- what drives such a huge difference?
- I understand that `numpy.select` is vectorised, whereas for example `pandas.DataFrame.apply()` is not. But isn't sqlite written in C? I would have expected speeds comparable to those of numpy.
- Is there anything I can do to speed up my select statement in sqlite? I have tried creating indices but that actually slows things down even more
- Specifically, when the table is small (ca. < 1,000 rows) then sqlite is faster, but once the table reaches 100,000 rows sqlite becomes slower than numpy.select.
- I am using SQLAlchemy because with the sqlite3 package I was having trouble exporting from sql back into pandas

With 100,000 rows the results are:
[image]

#### Minimal, reproducible example

I have a toy example below. Please note I time the `select` statement separately from the importing/exporting of the table between pandas and sqlite.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import text
import time
start = time.time()
time_df = pd.DataFrame()
time_df['start'] = [start]
rng = np.random.default_rng()
myrows = int(100e3)
mycols = 20
df = pd.DataFrame(data=rng.integers(low=0, high=100, size=(myrows, mycols)))
df['my field'] = np.arange(0,myrows)
df['y'] = df['my field']*2
df['city'] = np.tile(['Paris','New York'],int(myrows/2))
df['mydate'] = pd.to_datetime("15-Jan-2023")

time_df['df creation'] = [time.time()]

df_date_cols = [col for col in df.columns if df[col].dtype == 'datetime64[ns]']
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=False)
conn_sqla = engine.connect()
df.to_sql('df', conn_sqla)
time_df['export to sql'] = [time.time()]
values = {'myx':1}

# conn_sqla.execute(text("CREATE INDEX idx_city ON df(city)"))
# conn_sqla.execute(text("CREATE INDEX idx_myfield ON df([my field])"))
conn_sqla.execute(text("""
                  CREATE TABLE df2 as SELECT m.*
                  , case when city = 'New York' then 'NY'
                      when [my field] > 50 then 'not NY; > 50'
                      else 'not NY; <= 50'
                      end as [New field]
                  from df m
                  where [my field] > :myx
                  """), values)
time_df['run SQL select'] = [time.time()]        
df_from_sql = pd.read_sql("df2", conn_sqla, parse_dates=df_date_cols)
conn_sqla.close()
time_df['import from SQL'] = [time.time()]

df_from_np = df.query("`my field` > 1").copy(deep=True)
conditions = {'NY': df_from_np['city'].eq("New York"),
              'not NY; > 50': df_from_np['my field'].gt(50)}

df_from_np['new field'] = np.select(conditions.values(), conditions.keys(), "not NY; <= 50")

time_df['np select'] = [time.time()]

def myfunc(city,value):
    if city == 'New York':
        return 'NY'
    elif value > 50:
        return'not NYY;  50'
    else:
        return 'not NY; <= 50'
    
df_apply = df.query("`my field` > 1").copy(deep=True)
df_apply['new field'] = df_apply.apply(lambda x: myfunc(x['city'], x['my field']), axis =1 )

time_df['df.apply'] = [time.time()]


time_df = time_df.transpose()
time_df['seconds elapsed'] = np.hstack([0, np.diff(time_df[0])])

print(time_df)
```

Answer (score 3):

It's somewhat difficult to interpret the timings in your example, because the sqlite part and the numpy part are doing quite different things. For the latter, everything happens in one context, whereas for the former, there's the unavoidable extra burden of converting the sqlite results to back to a data-frame. If it's assumed pandas is already using the most efficient means of doing that, there may not be much you can do to *dramatically* improve things.

However, it seems clear that duplicating the table in the sqlite statement is always going to be a major bottleneck. (For me, `CREATE TABLE` is over 75 times more expensive than the `SELECT` alone). If that unnecessary extra step is eliminated, your example will run significantly faster:

```
...
sql = text("""
      SELECT m.*
      , case when city = 'New York' then 'NY'
          when [my field] > 50 then 'not NY; > 50'
          else 'not NY; <= 50'
          end as [New field]
      from df m
      where [my field] > :myx
      """)
df_from_sql = pd.read_sql(sql, conn_sqla, params=values, parse_dates=df_date_cols)
time_df['import from SQL'] = [time.time()]
print(df_from_sql)
conn_sqla.close()

df_from_np = df.query("`my field` > 1").copy(deep=True)
conditions = {'NY': df_from_np['city'].eq("New York"),
              'not NY; > 50': df_from_np['my field'].gt(50)}

df_from_np['new field'] = np.select(conditions.values(), conditions.keys(), "not NY; <= 50")
print(df_from_np)
    ...
```

Output:

```
       index   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  my field       y      city     mydate      New field
0          2  27  86  91  97  95  73  88  26  31  59   9  46  48  65  15   7  75  55  37  61         2       4     Paris 2023-01-15  not NY; <= 50
1          3  30  57  88  30  72  75  90  88  94  11  36  85  84  88  42  17  18  58   3  87         3       6  New York 2023-01-15             NY
2          4  86  40   8  31  88  71  96  30  62  40   7  38  64  92  87  88  82  54  55  79         4       8     Paris 2023-01-15  not NY; <= 50
3          5  24   2  74  59  91  59  15  69  79  71  41  57  35  45  22  28  18   5  40  13         5      10  New York 2023-01-15             NY
4          6  57   5  24  44  62   4  81  66  51  49  88  90  59  73  98  22  15  52   2  33         6      12     Paris 2023-01-15  not NY; <= 50
...      ...  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..       ...     ...       ...        ...            ...
99993  99995  49  88  57  25  37  33  57  86  76  23  15   4  70  14  80   7  61   6  63  43     99995  199990  New York 2023-01-15             NY
99994  99996  24  60  71  19  80  78  55  69   6  18  41  25  21  89  13  10  22  27  42  54     99996  199992     Paris 2023-01-15   not NY; > 50
99995  99997  97  51  29  51  27  26  71  97  42  66  67  69  51  56  66  61  56   6  74  41     99997  199994  New York 2023-01-15             NY
99996  99998   2  27  45  39  62  78  47  30   3  37   3  73  49  45  43   2  25   3  20  14     99998  199996     Paris 2023-01-15   not NY; > 50
99997  99999  83  97  51  94  52  24  95  41  16  78  71  29  37  80  96  51  32  51  83  81     99999  199998  New York 2023-01-15             NY

[99998 rows x 26 columns]
        0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  my field       y      city     mydate      new field
2      27  86  91  97  95  73  88  26  31  59   9  46  48  65  15   7  75  55  37  61         2       4     Paris 2023-01-15  not NY; <= 50
3      30  57  88  30  72  75  90  88  94  11  36  85  84  88  42  17  18  58   3  87         3       6  New York 2023-01-15             NY
4      86  40   8  31  88  71  96  30  62  40   7  38  64  92  87  88  82  54  55  79         4       8     Paris 2023-01-15  not NY; <= 50
5      24   2  74  59  91  59  15  69  79  71  41  57  35  45  22  28  18   5  40  13         5      10  New York 2023-01-15             NY
6      57   5  24  44  62   4  81  66  51  49  88  90  59  73  98  22  15  52   2  33         6      12     Paris 2023-01-15  not NY; <= 50
...    ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..       ...     ...       ...        ...            ...
99995  49  88  57  25  37  33  57  86  76  23  15   4  70  14  80   7  61   6  63  43     99995  199990  New York 2023-01-15             NY
99996  24  60  71  19  80  78  55  69   6  18  41  25  21  89  13  10  22  27  42  54     99996  199992     Paris 2023-01-15   not NY; > 50
99997  97  51  29  51  27  26  71  97  42  66  67  69  51  56  66  61  56   6  74  41     99997  199994  New York 2023-01-15             NY
99998   2  27  45  39  62  78  47  30   3  37   3  73  49  45  43   2  25   3  20  14     99998  199996     Paris 2023-01-15   not NY; > 50
99999  83  97  51  94  52  24  95  41  16  78  71  29  37  80  96  51  32  51  83  81     99999  199998  New York 2023-01-15             NY

[99998 rows x 25 columns]
                            0  seconds elapsed
start            1.684863e+09         0.000000
df creation      1.684863e+09         0.024940
export to sql    1.684863e+09         1.979611
import from SQL  1.684863e+09         1.046256
np select        1.684863e+09         0.076970
df.apply         1.684863e+09         0.855437
```

Comment: That's great! Do you happen to know if there is a way to speed up the create table statement? In most cases your solution is perfect, but in some cases I need to create two tables, merge them and then export the result back to pandas.

Comment: Actually, this way you are not timing the execution of the SQL select statement, but only the creation of a SQLAlchemy Text object. In your code, the SQL statement is run at the same time you import into pandas. But, as can be seen above, your solution is still faster than what I had put together

Comment: @Pythonistaanonymous Sorry, yes, I didn't notice that the timings work out differently when running your full example. It really makes no sense to include the "run SQL select" timing, since I've folded it all into the import step. I've now amended my answer accordingly. As for your other question: are you sure you *really* need to create two tables? I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but can't you use some kind of `UNION` instead?